# Raising exception during logging

Tags: python, exception, logging

In Python 3 is there a way to raise exception during logging? I mean, can I somehow configure the standard `logging` module to raise an exception when `logging.error(e)` is done?

Answer (score 2):

You don't normally log an error by calling `logging.error(e)`. You normally call

```
logging.error('my message', exc_info=True)
```

OR

```
logging.error('my message', exc_info=e)  # Where e is the exception object
```

That being said, you can extend the [`Logger`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger) class to do this:

```
from logging import Logger, setLoggerClass
from sys import exc_info

class ErrLogger(Logger):
    def error(msg, *args, **kwargs):
        super().error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
        err = kwargs.get('exc_info')
        if not isintsance(err, Exception):
            _, err, _ = exc_info()
            if err is None:
                err = SomeDefaultError(msg)  # You decide what to raise
        raise err
```

Now register the new class using the [`setLoggerClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass) function:

```
setLoggerClass(ErrLogger)
```

Setting a custom logger with a custom [`error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.error) is likely a more reliable method than overriding the module level [`error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.error), which only operates on the root logger.

The method show here will raise errors in the following order:

1. An error passed through the `exc_info` keyword-only argument.
2. The error currently in the process of being handled.
3. `SomeDefaultError` that you designate.

If you want to forego this process, replace everything after `super().error(msg, *args, **kwargs)` with just `raise SomeDefaultError(...)`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I've used simplified version, with `raise MyError(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace the method by your own method.

```
import logging

def except_only(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception(msg)
logging.error = except_only     # do not use () here!
logging.error("Log an error")
```

Problem: you need to remember the original method if you want logging + an exception.

```
import logging

old_logging_error = logging.error   # do not use () here!
def new_logging_error(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    global old_logging_error
    old_logging_error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    raise Exception(msg)
logging.error = new_logging_error   # do not use () here!

logging.error("Log an error")
```